# simpleXML deserialization issue in java

Tags: java, simple-framework

For my project, I'm trying to deserialize an XML string I'm receiving from a web service.  I'm new to SimpleXML but for the most part I've had no trouble with it.  I've read the docs and tutorials and have it working for everything except the following response string:

```
<response id="123456789" result="supported" state="new">supported</response>
```

The problem is that the base 'response' object has the 'supported' text in a non-element or non-attribute way.  Here's my current Response class.

```
@Root(name="response")
public class Response {

    @Attribute
    private String id;

    @Attribute
    private String result;

    @Attribute
    private String state;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
}
```

How can I format my Response class in java to get this to deserialize properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to add another field and annotate with `@Text`, like this [**example**](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#text)